# How to check if and object is empty (deep)?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Take this:

```
var lists:{
  item1:{}
  ,item2:{}
  ,item3:{}
  ,item4:{}
}
```

Since it's substantially empty, I want a function (maybe but not necessarily a _lodash one) that checks it and say that is empty.

Something like

```
is_empty(lists) // >> true (because every property resolves to an empty object)
```

How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the values of the object and check if all of them are empty:

```
var lists = {
  item1:{},
  item2:{},
  item3:{},
  item4:{}
}

//ES6:
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(k => !Object.keys(obj[k]).length)
}

console.log(isEmpty(lists));

// ES5
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(k) {
        return !Object.keys(obj[k]).length}
    )
}

console.log(isEmpty(lists));
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm an old fashioned js programmer, not into this kind of operators (=>) yet :P is it crossbrowser or does it need some kind of precompilation?

Comment: @Stratboy `=>` is an arrow function which is a part of ES6 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It is already quite heavily adopted by all major browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) without a need to precompile. I've added a ES5 version as well just in case, it should work in browsers that do not support ES6 arrow functions

Comment: Ok they're still not really crossbrowser: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions - lack of support in IE11 and Android < 4.4 is enough to use a precompiler to me :) thank you very much for all explanations and the es5 version :)

Answer (score 2):

If `lists` is always an object of objects, you can iterate over all values with `Object.values` and check that each value (inner object) has no keys:

```js
const isEmpty = outer => Object.values(outer).every(
  inner => Object.keys(inner).length === 0
);

var lists = {
  item1:{}
  ,item2:{}
  ,item3:{}
  ,item4:{}
}
var lists2 = {
  item1:{}
  ,item2:{}
  ,item3:{}
  ,item4:{}
  ,item5:{ foo: 'bar' }
}
console.log(isEmpty(lists));
console.log(isEmpty(lists2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution with check for the emptyness of the eternally nested object.
Note: This will treat empty string `''` and boolean `false` as empty as well. If you need special support for stings then may be you can do some tweaking in the below code.

```
const isDeeplyEmpty = item => {
  if(typeof item === 'boolean') return !item;
  else if(typeof item === 'number') return false;
  else if(typeof item === 'object') {
    return Object.keys(item).every(k => {
      if(['object', 'boolean', 'number'].includes(typeof item[k])) {
        return isDeeplyEmpty(item[k]);
      }
      return _.isEmpty(item[k]);
    })
  }
  return !item;
};
```